# run time error in java program converting integers into Roman numerals

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

As an assignment in my object-oriented programming course we were asked to right a program that converts an integer between 1 and 3999. We are not allowed to use arrays or loops. Anyway, below is my code which has no errors that I can discern but something is preventing the program from running successfully. The following is the display on the console when a random number (let's use 100) is put into the phrase "in.nextInt()":

"Enter a number between 1 and 3999 to begin:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 100

```
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1934)
at java.util.Scanner.buildIntegerPatternString(Scanner.java:447)
at java.util.Scanner.integerPattern(Scanner.java:467)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
at IntegerToRomanNumeral.main(IntegerToRomanNumeral.java:13)"
```

Most of this message is gibberish to me but I'm really having trouble understanding why the number 100 is interpreted as being "out of range" when my range is 1-3999.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 3999 to begin: ");
int input = in.nextInt( );

    //we want to avoid 0, negative numbers & numbers greater than 3999
if (input < 1 || input > 3999);
    System.out.print("Invalid Number!");
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 3999.");

        //creating strings to be defined for the different cases later
    String romanOnes = ("");
    String romanTens = ("");
    String romanHundreds = ("");
    String romanThousands = ("");

    //separating the ones, tens, hundreds & thousands from within the input
int ones1 = input % 10;
    int ones = ones1;

    int tens1 = input % 10;
        if (tens1 < 10)
        { tens1 = input / 10; }
        else
        { tens1 = (tens1 % 100) - ones; }

        int tens = tens1;

    int hundreds1 = input % 100;
        if (hundreds1 < 10)
        { hundreds1 = input / 100; }
        else
        { hundreds1 = (hundreds1 % 1000) - tens - ones; }

        int hundreds = hundreds1;

    int thousands1 = input % 1000;
        if (thousands1 < 4)
        { thousands1 = input / 1000; }
        else
        { thousands1 = (thousands1 % 10000) - hundreds - tens - ones; }

        int thousands = thousands1;

        // different cases for the "ones" and their conversion in to Roman numerals
    if (ones == 0)
        {romanOnes = ("");}
        while (ones == 1);
            {romanOnes = ("I");}
        while (ones == 2);
            {romanOnes = ("II");}   
        while (ones == 3);
            {romanOnes = ("III");}
        while (ones == 4);
            {romanOnes = ("IV");}
        while (ones == 5);                  
                            {romanOnes = ("V");}
        while (ones == 6);
            {romanOnes = ("VI");}
        while (ones == 7);
            {romanOnes = ("VII");}
        while (ones == 8);
            {romanOnes = ("VIII");}
        while (ones == 9);
            {romanOnes = ("IX");}   

            // different cases for the "tens" and their conversion in to Roman numerals
        if (tens == 0)
            {romanTens = ("");}
        while (tens == 1);
            {romanTens = ("X");}
        while (tens == 2);
            {romanTens = ("XX");}   
        while (tens == 3);
            {romanTens = ("XXX");}
        while (tens == 4);
            {romanTens = ("XL");}
        while (tens == 5);
            {romanTens = ("L");}
        while (tens == 6);
            {romanTens = ("LX");}
        while (tens == 7);
            {romanTens = ("LXX");}
        while (tens == 8);
            {romanTens = ("LXXX");}
        while (tens == 9);
            {romanTens = ("XC");}   

            // different cases for the "hundreds" and their conversion in to Roman numerals
        if (hundreds == 0)
            {romanHundreds = ("");}
        while (hundreds == 1);
            {romanHundreds = ("C");}
        while (hundreds == 2);
            {romanHundreds = ("CC");}   
        while (hundreds == 3);
            {romanHundreds = ("CCC");}
        while (hundreds == 4);
            {romanHundreds = ("CD");}
        while (hundreds == 5);
            {romanHundreds = ("D");}
        while (hundreds == 6);
            {romanHundreds = ("DC");}
        while (hundreds == 7);
            {romanHundreds = ("DCC");}
        while (hundreds == 8);
            {romanHundreds = ("DCCC");}
        while (hundreds == 9);
            {romanHundreds = ("CM");}   

            // different cases for the "thousands" and their conversion in to Roman numerals
        if (thousands == 0)
            {romanThousands = ("");}
        while (thousands == 1);
            {romanThousands = ("M");}
        while (thousands == 2);
            {romanThousands = ("MM");}  
        while (thousands == 3);
            {romanThousands = ("MMM");} 

            //Concatenating all strings to produce the complete Roman numeral
        String roman = (romanThousands + romanHundreds + romanTens + romanOnes);

            //output & goodbye message
        System.out.println(input + "in roman numerals is: " + roman);
        System.out.println("Thank you and goodbye!");   

}

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Not allowed to use arrays or loops? Might as well be told that you have to paint your program on the side of the building with the blood of goats. Anyway, you need to use a debugger.

Comment: This "**gibberish*" message means that your are attempting to access character(s) in a position (`index`) that is greater than string length.

Comment: For debugging purposes wrap your `in.nextInt( );` in `if (in.hasNextInt)` statement.  You may also want to post your **entire** `main` method.

Comment: "*... when a random number (let's use 100) is put into the phrase "`in.nextInt()`"*" Please explain what you actually did: entered 100 through console or put it as a parameter of `in.nextInt()` method.